# implement MS Update in my application

Tags: windows

Originally I wanted to ask, whether or how my Apps can be updated via the Microsoft Update Routine. Since Microsoft introduced their Windows Store in Windows 8, my question is somehow outdated. Nevertheless, if anyone know a way to get apps updated via MS Update in Windows 7 and previous Versions, please let me know.